# tidyverse interfering with ggplot2? cannot access map_data

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Running these commands in the console, the output is:

```
> cty0 = ggplot2::map_data("county")
> library(tidyverse)
Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
Loading tidyverse: tibble
Loading tidyverse: tidyr
Loading tidyverse: readr
Loading tidyverse: purrr
Loading tidyverse: dplyr
Conflicts with tidy packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
filter(): dplyr, stats
lag():    dplyr, stats
map():    purrr, maps
> cty0 = ggplot2::map_data("county")
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list
```

I can call `map_data("county")` fine until `tidyverse`is loaded, then it fails. How do I load a county map data with `tidyverse` loaded?

Comment: I'm guessing that the items below the dashed line are from the console messages, but you really should clarify that. Seems likely that the `map` function in 'purrr' is masking the `map` function in the 'maps' package. You could reverse the order of loading tidyverse and maps if there were a reason that you needed the (geographic notion of) "mapping" more than you needed the (functional-computer language notion of) "mapping". You probably need to start a new session for that to succeed. The `library` function checks to see of a package is already loaded and if so does nothing.

Comment: I'd mention this to the developers of tidyverse as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transferred the comment from above after testing:

> I'm guessing that the items below the dashed line are from the console messages <strike>, but you really should clarify that</strike> . Seems likely that the map function in 'purrr' is masking the map function in the 'maps' package. You could reverse the order of loading tidyverse and maps if there were a reason that you needed the (geographic notion of) "mapping" more than you needed the (functional-computer language notion of) "mapping". You probably need to start a new session for that to succeed. The library function checks to see of a package is already loaded and if so does nothing.

A comment on terminology. My guess is that the computer operation of "mapping" is actually a contraction from "multiple application" (of a function to interim results). If there were a chance to go back and rename it to something that would be similar to a geographic concept, it might be named `route()`-ing. A geographic "map" would seem to be a static two or three-dimensional object or "mapping" to be placement of positions on such an object.

Seems to succeed:

```
# In a fresh session (and my profile attaches ggplot2 by default)
> library(tidyverse)
Loading tidyverse: tibble
Loading tidyverse: tidyr
Loading tidyverse: readr
Loading tidyverse: purrr
Loading tidyverse: dplyr
Conflicts with tidy packages ---------------------------------
combine():   dplyr, Hmisc  # loaded in my .Rprofile; also attaches gglot2
filter():    dplyr, stats
lag():       dplyr, stats
matches():   dplyr, sos   #from .Rprofile; doesn't seem to clobber findFn function
src():       dplyr, Hmisc
summarize(): dplyr, Hmisc
> cty0 = ggplot2::map_data("county")

Attaching package: ‘maps’

The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    map
```

Comment: I had just done the opposite! `purrr::map` but this works equally well. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why `ggplot2::map_data` actually attaches `maps`?

Comment: From the function help page: "Description

Easily turn data from the maps package in to a data frame suitable for plotting with ggplot2."

Comment: I'd say it was a ggplot2 bug in `map_data` - it should say `fortify(maps::map(....` or otherwise explicitly import the map function from the maps package.

Comment: You're probably held in higher esteem by Hadley than am I, especially with regard to mapping functions, so can you file the bug report?

Comment: There's some bug in the maps package that requires it to be attached in order to actually retrieve map data

Comment: it boils down to `get("countyMapEnv")` which fails if maps package not attached. Will report.

Comment: The next version of the maps package (v3.2, on github but not yet submitted) should fix the requirement to attach the package.