# Cannot run map_data("state")

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to work on a US map in R. I have done it a lot of times but this time it gives me this error when I try to load:

```
us<- map_data("state")
Error in .C(C_map_type, as.character(mapbase), integer(1)) : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (2), expecting 0 for ''
```

I have ggmap and ggplot2 libraries loaded. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need the 'maps' package along with ggmap.

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
us<- map_data("state")
```

This should work

Comment: Still no luck
Gives me this:

Error in .C(C_map_type, as.character(mapbase), integer(1)) : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (2), expecting 22 for 'Kit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio Safari/538.1 Qt/5.4.1'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are bugs in `tidyverse` which interferes with `ggplot2` maps functionality.  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205731/tidyverse-interfering-with-ggplot2-cannot-access-map-data).

This works in a clean, freshly-restarted R session:

```
us <- ggplot2::map_data("state")
```

However, this does not:

```
library(tidyverse)
us2 = ggplot2::map_data("state")
```

Comment: I noticed sometimes it worked and sometimes it doesn't. I tried fresh restart of both system and R but no success. Anyways I'm over it now. Thanks