# Cannot run map_data(“state”)

Tags: r, rmaps

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066628/cannot-run-map-datastate), I have the following problem.

```
states <- map_data("state")
```

> Error in .C(C_map_type, as.character(mapbase), integer(1)) : 
>           Incorrect number of arguments (2), expecting 0 for ''

I have the latest maps library installed too. I'm using RStudio version 1.1.383 with R 3.4.3 on Windows 10. I have gotten this command to run previously, and in the same code it is not running.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Its working fine for me, my suggestion is to reinstall "maps", check if that works or run a `conflicts()` first and see if "maps" is in conflict with any other package or you may try `ggplot2::map_data("state")`

Comment: I have tried re-installing 'maps' as well as the alternative command you've suggested, and neither work. conflicts() does not present any relevant info for this issue